# How to use commas in these particular situations

Tags: commas, mathematics

I am a mathematicians, and there are some "sentence structures" that constantly appear in my work. I have some doubt about how "commas" behave in them.

I am well aware of the comma used between coordinators when independent clauses are joined. For example, "Let A be a ring, and let B be an A-module". But I have troubles in the following situations.

Which one is correct?

1. If A is a module and B is a ring, then A is a group and B is a set.
2. If A is a module, and B is a ring, then A is a group, and B is a set.

Which one is correct?

3. Let A be a ring such that B is an A-module and C is an A-algebra.
4. Let A be a ring such that B is an A-module, and C is an A-algebra.

Which one is correct?

5. Suppose that A is a ring and B is a module.
6. Suppose that A is a ring, and B is a module.

Summarising, are the clauses in these situations considered independent? Does the answer depend on the length of the sentences?

Comment: ... if you pronounce them differently. Many people don't, and wonder where to put commas. In mathematical parlance, they don't matter. Full stops like semicolons and periods do, but commas don't. The closer the parlance is to English, the more commas (or, more exactly, one of the intonation curves that we represent in writing with commas) you will probly need. But the simplest math joke I know needs them: "Let G be a ring, let F be a group, and let R be a field".

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I also have added a comment at the answer below, please let me know if you have more comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me note that I am only giving some suggestions. Grammars and style guides often have varying rules for comma usage, so there is no definitive answer.

> If A is a module and B is a ring, then A is a group and B is a set.

The comma sets off an adverbial clause that appears at the beginning of the main (matrix) clause. This is common and fine.

> If A is a module, and B is a ring, then A is a group, and B is a set.

If the second of two conjuncts in a series is nonrestrictive or parenthetical, then commas can surround it (as well as the preceding conjunction). However, "B is a ring" seems to be an important element of this sentence, so it should probably not be surrounded by commmas.

When one element (such as an adverbial clause) applies to two main clauses, then it is common to connect those main clauses with only a coordinating conjunction. Thus, most writers would also omit the last comma in this sentence.

> Let A be a ring such that B is an A-module and C is an A-algebra.

This is fine.

> Let A be a ring such that B is an A-module, and C is an A-algebra.

This comma appears to work with "and" to connect two clauses. However, while we normally connect main clauses that way, these are both subordinate clauses (introduced by the subordinator "that" or "such that"). Thus, the comma is best omitted.

> Suppose that A is a ring and B is a module.

This is fine.

> Suppose that A is a ring, and B is a module.

Again, both clauses are subordinate, introduced by the subordinator "that". As with the previous sentence, the comma is normally omitted.

Comment: Thank you, I believe exactly what you have written, and it is nice to have a confirmation. Just a final question: What if, is a statement of a theorem, we have something like this:
Theorem. Let A be a commutative ring, and let M be an A-module. Then M is an abelian group and A acts on M in a suitable way.
Is this correct without comma? I think what you have said applies here with "Then...".

Comment: @Losten Yes, "then" applies to both main clauses, so it is certainly acceptable to omit the comma. Again, practices vary, so some people will include a comma there, but it is very common to omit it.